# Update query not firing properly. Update does not reflect

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

My Code Behind File is UpdatePublication.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace SBAIMS
{
    public partial class UpdatePublisher : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["P_Id"] != null)
            {
                string s = Request.QueryString["P_Id"].ToString();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=AP\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=SBAIMS;Integrated Security=True");
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Publication_Master where P_Id='" + s + "' ", con);
                SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adptr.Fill(ds, "Publication_Master");
                if (ds.Tables["Publication_Master"].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    upub.Text = ds.Tables["Publication_Master"].Rows[0]["Publication"].ToString();
                    upname.Text = ds.Tables["Publication_Master"].Rows[0]["Publisher"].ToString();
                    upc1.Text = ds.Tables["Publication_Master"].Rows[0]["P_Contact"].ToString();
                    upc2.Text = ds.Tables["Publication_Master"].Rows[0]["P_Contact2"].ToString();
                    upemail.Text = ds.Tables["Publication_Master"].Rows[0]["P_Email"].ToString();
                    upban.Text = ds.Tables["Publication_Master"].Rows[0]["P_BankAccount"].ToString();
                }
                con.Close();
            }


        }
        protected void submitupdatepub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                string s = Request.QueryString["P_Id"].ToString();
                SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=AP\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=SBAIMS;Integrated Security=True");
                con2.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Publication_Master SET Publication='" + upub.Text + "', Publisher='" + upname.Text + "', P_Contact='" + upc1.Text + "', P_Contact2='" + upc2.Text + "', P_Email='" + upemail.Text + "', P_BankAccount='" + upban.Text + "' WHERE P_Id='"+s+"'", con2);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();         
                con2.Close();
                Response.Redirect("~/UPublisher.aspx");

        }
    }
}
```

My ASPX file is UpdatePublication.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Update Publication" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="UpdatePublication.aspx.cs" Inherits="SBAIMS.UpdatePublisher" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div id="updatepublisher">
        <table width="100%" class="table table-borderless table-responsive">
            <tr>
                <td width="50%" style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <div class="panel panel-success" id="updatepub">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4>
                                <b>Update Publication.</b></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <h5>
                                Update data about Publication.</h5>
                            <br />
                            <div align="center">
                                <asp:Label ID="updatepubsubmit" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Text="Update Was Successful !!"
                                    CssClass="alert alert-success alcntr" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <table class="table table-borderless table-responsive fs15" align="center" style="width: 500px; background-color: transparent;">
                           <tr>
                                    <td width="40%">
                                        Publication Name
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="60%">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="upub" CssClass="form-control fs15" autocomplete="off" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Field Required"
                                            ControlToValidate="upub" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Size="Medium"
                                            CssClass="rfvlabel" ValidationGroup="rfvup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Publisher (/Distributor) Name
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="upname" CssClass="form-control fs15" autocomplete="off" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Field Required"
                                            ControlToValidate="upname" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Size="Medium"
                                            CssClass="rfvlabel" ValidationGroup="rfvup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                              <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator9" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Enter characters or valid symbols" ControlToValidate="upname" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Size="Medium"
                                            CssClass="rfvlabel" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$" ValidationGroup="rfvup"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Contact No. 1
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="upc1" CssClass="form-control fs15" autocomplete="off" placeholder="optional" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator10" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Numbers Only" 
                                            ControlToValidate="upc1" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Size="Medium"
                                            CssClass="rfvlabel" ValidationExpression="^([0-9]*)$" ValidationGroup="rfvup"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Contact No. 2
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                       <asp:TextBox ID="upc2" CssClass="form-control fs15" autocomplete="off" placeholder="optional" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator11" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Numbers Only" 
                                            ControlToValidate="upc2" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Size="Medium"
                                            CssClass="rfvlabel" ValidationExpression="^([0-9]*)$" ValidationGroup="rfvup"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Publisher Bank A/C No.
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="upban" CssClass="form-control fs15" autocomplete="off" placeholder="optional" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                       <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator12" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Numbers Only" 
                                            ControlToValidate="upban" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Size="Medium"
                                            CssClass="rfvlabel" ValidationExpression="^([0-9]*)$" ValidationGroup="rfvup"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Pub. Email ID
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="upemail" CssClass="form-control fs15" autocomplete="off" placeholder="optional" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator13" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Please Enter Valid Email ID"
                                            Display="Dynamic" CssClass="rfvlabel" ControlToValidate="upemail" ValidationGroup="rfvup"
                                            ValidationExpression="^([0-9a-zZ-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <table class="table table-borderless table-responsive" align="center" style="width: 300px;
            background-color: transparent;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <asp:Button ID="submitupdatepublisher" runat="server" OnClick="submitupdatepub_Click" class="btn btn-success btn-block"
                        Font-Size="Large" Text="Update" ValidationGroup="rfvup" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div> 
    </td> 
    <td></td>
    </tr> 
    </table> 
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

The update doesn't work successfully. I mean it does not reflect in database. It just according to code, redirects to the specified page. Please help me where i am going wrong.

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL you are passing to the SqlCommand object? I am betting it is not quite as you expect.  Have you stepped through it in a debugger?

Comment: As you sql operation is not breaking with any error. I think value of s (Request.QueryString["P_Id"].ToString()) might be setting to something which is not matching with db values. Still as Rob suggesting debugging is best thing to go with.

Comment: @Rob yes i did put a breakpoint and analyzed. The value of s is being acquired properly but the value of textboxes (.text part) is not matching with the newly updated part. i.e., the textboxes reflect the old filled values and not the new changed values.

Comment: Please don't put this code in to a production web server.  It's just begging for a SQL Injection Attack.  You should be passing in the ID trhough a parameter object, not as a string literal in the query.

Comment: Thank you @BradleyUffner for your concern. I will put a parameterized query.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is now solved. I thank all of you for your concerns.

The problem was solved by just putting if not postback condition.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{

    if (Request.QueryString["P_Id"] != null)
    {
                            ....
    }
}
```